# Filter search results by multiple filters in one operation

Tags: c#, linq

I want to filter search results by multiple filters at once. Is it possible to reduce the number of if statements?
My code:

```
    public IEnumerable<Article> Search(ArticleFiltersModel filters, ArticleSortOptions? options)
    {
        var result = Mapper.Map<IQueryable<Article>>(_unitOfWork.Articles.AsQueryable());
        if (filters != null)
            Filter(ref result, filters);
        else
            result = result.Where(article => article.IsAvailable == true);
        if (options.HasValue)
            Sort(ref result, options.Value);
        return result;
    }

    private void Filter(ref IQueryable<Article> articles, ArticleFiltersModel filters)
    {
        if (filters.IsAvailable.HasValue)
            articles = articles.Where(article => article.IsAvailable == filters.IsAvailable);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filters.Name))
            articles = articles.Where(article => article.Title.Contains(filters.Name));
        if (filters.AreaFrom.HasValue)
            articles = articles.Where(article => article.House.Area >= filters.AreaFrom);
        if (filters.AreaTo.HasValue)
            articles = articles.Where(article => article.House.Area <= filters.AreaTo);
        if (filters.PriceFrom.HasValue)
            articles = articles.Where(article => article.House.Area >= filters.PriceFrom);
        if (filters.PriceTo.HasValue)
            articles = articles.Where(article => article.House.Area <= filters.PriceTo);
        if (filters.Type.HasValue)
            articles = articles.Where(article => article.House.Type == filters.Type);
        if (filters.RoomsCount.HasValue)
            articles = articles.Where(article => article.House.RoomsCount == filters.RoomsCount);
        if (filters.Floors.HasValue)
            articles = articles.Where(article => article.House.FloorsCount == filters.Floors);
        if (filters.Floor.HasValue)
            articles = articles.Where(article => article.House.Floor == filters.Floor);
        if (filters.HasParking.HasValue)
            articles = articles.Where(article => article.House.HasParking == filters.HasParking);
        if (filters.WithHomeAppliances.HasValue)
            articles = articles.Where(article => article.House.WithHomeAppliances == filters.WithHomeAppliances);
    }
```

My filter model:

```
public class ArticleFiltersModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal? AreaFrom { get; set; }
    public decimal? AreaTo { get; set; }
    public decimal? PriceFrom { get; set; }
    public decimal? PriceTo { get; set; }
    public HouseType? Type { get; set; }
    public int? RoomsCount { get; set; }
    public bool? IsFurnished { get; set; }
    public int? Floors { get; set; }
    public int? Floor { get; set; }
    public bool? HasParking { get; set; }
    public bool? WithHomeAppliances { get; set; }
    public bool? IsAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

### UPDATE

Article.cs:

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int HouseId { get; set; }
    public House House { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Added { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Realtor> Realtors { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

House.cs:

```
public enum HouseType { House, Apartment, Condo, Cooperative, Land, Office,
                        Restaurant, Bar, Storage, Building, Other }
public class House
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Area { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int RoomsCount { get; set; }
    public bool IsFurnished { get; set; }
    public int FloorsCount { get; set; }
    public int Floor { get; set; }
    public bool HasParking { get; set; }
    public bool WithHomeAppliances { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public HouseType Type { get; set; }
    public int PhotoId { get; set; }
    public Image Photo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/143094/52662 to see if that helps you

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Could you also post the code for _Article_ for completeness?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I read it as one long `AND` operation where the result is the articles that satisfy all the valid predicates. You could therefore build an enumerable of valid predicates in an extension method:

```
  public static class ArticleFilterExtensions
  {
    public static IEnumerable<Predicate<Article>> GetValidPredicates(this ArticleFiltersModel filter)
    {
      if (filter.IsAvailable.HasValue)
        yield return a => a.IsAvailable == filter.IsAvailable;
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Name))
        yield return a => a.Title.Contains(filter.Name);
      if (filter.AreaFrom.HasValue)
        yield return a => a.House.Area >= filter.AreaFrom;
      // etc.

      if (filter.WithHomeAppliances.HasValue)
        yield return a => a.House.WithHomeAppliances == filter.WithHomeAppliances;
    }
  }
```

And your filter method could then be reduced to:

```
private void Filter(ref IQueryable<Article> articles, ArticleFiltersModel filters)
{
  var predicates = filters.GetValidPredicates().ToList();
  articles = articles.Where(a => predicates.All(p => p(a)));
}
```

You could then easily create an `OR` filter as

```
private void OrFilter(ref IQueryable<Article> articles, ArticleFiltersModel filters)
{
  var predicates = filters.GetValidPredicates().ToList();
  articles = articles.Where(a => predicates.Any(p => p(a)));
}
```

`

Comment: +1 for using a single call to _Where_ and reusing predicates for  _or_, _and_

Comment: @dfhwze: Maybe `GetValidPredicates()` should return an array or a readonly list instead of `yield`-ing?

Comment: I think we are micro-optimising in such case. But a comparative test with a huge amount of predicates could _yield_ us more info.

Comment: @dfhwze this would be a pretty academic test because which sane person is using _a huge amount of predicates_ in the real-world? :-P

Comment: @t3chb0t Have you never worked in the _banking sector_? :p

Comment: @dfhwze I guess I should answer this question with _luckily_ not insteady of _unfortunately_ haha

Comment: @HenrikHansen Why do you add `ToList()` after `GetValidPredicates()`? `IQueryable` defers execution; `ToList()` forces immediate execution.

Comment: @MY_G: The idea is that by calling `ToList()` the predicates will only be created once, while without they will be recreated for each article in the where method

Answer (score 5):

I would further improve [Henrik Hansen](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/225148/59161)'s code by throwing away the `if`s and integrating the preconditions inside in the queries so they would become:

```
yield articles.Where(article => !filters.IsAvailable.HasValue || article.IsAvailable == filters.IsAvailable);
```

This would not only make it more readable but would show us that now we can actually generate these expressions (probably with [Jesse C. Slicer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/225146/59161)'s code) which would save us a lot of typing.

Comment: Henrik returns predicates, later used to get articles, where you return articles directly. Did you mean to inline the _if_ in the predicates or directly in the result set?

Comment: In this way you query every filter for every article where mine filter the filters once and then only use the valid filters on each article.

Comment: @HenrikHansen of course but the sql-server doesn't care, it can optmize it away... I'm pretty sure of that.

Comment: @HenrikHansen I've had discussions about situations like this before. Should a developer write code, having optimisations by the used API and/or compiler in mind or not? I don't have an answer to that question.

Comment: @dfhwze I cannot find any signifficant difference in the two execution plans, even with the help of the execution-plan comparer. I wonder whether someone already has asked this question on stack-overflow...

Comment: @t3chb0t - there are a lot of things at play here. I can tell you that I have seen an 80% reduction in cost in EF for a complex query by "flattening" the predicates into a single `Where` rather than using multiple `Where` calls. Projection (Select) and navigation property use can have big impacts on generated SQL - hard to test without a specific case!

Comment: @RobH I believe you. Even LINQPad often generates a more efficient query than EF. Running LINQ there and then just copy-pasting it for EF means a high risk of client-sinde execution. I now by default disable this feature. It might be similar with multiple `where`s. EF silently switches from server queries to linq. This is a performance killer for largs databases. [Client vs. Server Evaluation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval). I find it should not be doing this. Only when explicitly enabled. Might be convenient for testing but not in production.

Answer (score 3):

Given an extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> NullWhere<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool?>> expression, bool? compare) => compare.HasValue
    ? source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(expression.Body, Expression.Constant((bool)compare)), expression.Parameters))
    : source;
```

You can then use:

```
articles = articles.NullWhere(article => article.IsAvailable, filters.IsAvailable);
```

Note this works for equality for nullable `bool`s - you'll have to create other extension methods for nullable `decimal`s with greater-than-or-equal-to, null/empty strings with `string.Contains()`, etc. But the principle will be the same behind each.

Comment: I'm contemplating whether Expresssion is really required here. Why not just use the Func instead?

Comment: @dfhwze expressions don't have to be required. They are cool by themselfes wherever used ;-]

Comment: @dfhwze oh, this could end up recursive... who would be generating who? A T4 template for generating expressions to generate T4 templates to generate code generating expressions generating T4 templates... a very deep rabitt hole.

Answer (score 2):

How about a generic extension method that takes a boolean and an expression, whereas the expression is only evaluated in case the boolean is true:

```
public static IQueryable<T> When<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source, bool trigger, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    if (trigger)
    {
        return source.Where(expression);
    }

    return source;
}
```

It allows you to chain the calls similar to what @t3chb0t suggested, but it will not even chain unnecessary filters:

```
articles = articles.When(filters.IsAvailable.HasValue, article => article.IsAvailable == filters.IsAvailable)
    .When(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filters.Name), article => article.Title.Contains(filters.Name));
```

Similarly it would be possible to write an even more generic method that doesn't take `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` as third parameter but an `Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>>>`, which would allow you to chain arbitrary methods (with a trigger).